# Was I wrong improving the tag wiki for drivers?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I really need to know why was [my edit](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/158569/4) [rolled back](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/158569/5). Because nobody asked me nor took the issue up to me. Don't get me wrong, I think No Time has done a well job updating them I felt that this time he messed it up so I was just fixing it. Was I so wrong that the edit should have been rolled back?

Comment: I found your edit to be efficient.

Answer (score 3):

My take on this was that the previous tag wiki which has been reinstated was a clear concise wiki that explained concepts in a very user friendly way.

Terminology was precisely defined in a layman way.

The edit you are referring to stripped out much of this user friendliness - it left just key terms such as "xorg" dangling - that to the layman doesnt mean very much.

As a quick straw unscientific poll, I asked my 13 year-old to read the edited version and then read the previous version.  The edited version she said that (and I quote) ... "dunno dad - dont know what it means".

The previous version she said "that read like a dictionary"

So apart from trying to produce a wiki item for teenager speak ... I would suggest it was correctly rolled back.  In many ways, my personal opinion is that the format is a template for all of our sadly neglected wiki's; its a format we should all be striving for.

Remember, wiki's are the first item a questioner sees when selecting tags - so ideally we should make them as user friendly as possible, with basic terminology precisely and unambiguously defined.

Comment: SO, you are saying that only the form was bad?

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes.  Your edit does not make sense or explains to a normal user who would enter `driver` that in the tag field.  They would think its the wrong tag.  Then upon reading this wiki on the tag, they would have more questions than answers.